# Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно реализовать вот такое обтекание текстом картинки в слайдере?

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно реализовать вот такое обтекание текстом картинки в слайдере?

Скриншот:
[image: skrin]

Comment: Через css / js никак. Нужно делать 2 одинаковые строки с текстом, с разным z-index. Чтобы одна строка над картинкой, другая под.

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)